# Open custom component from angular interceptor

Tags: angular, components, interceptor

Is it possible in angular to open custom component (dialog window with form) from interceptor when i get specific error from backend? I'm trying to find solution working solution for that and can't.

Comment: which modal library you are using?

Comment: @AakashGarg ngx-bootstrap

Comment: added solution below

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your modal component name is MyModalComponent and you want to open it at, your interceptor will be like

```
    export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
     constructor(modalService: BsModalService) {}
     intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       return next.handle(request)
         .pipe(
           catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
             if(error.status === '404') {
             this.modalService.show(MyModalComponent, {});
             return throwError(errorMessage);
             }
           })
         )
     }

}
```